# How to get child elements of dragged element in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have drag and drop function on my web page. The dragged div contains 2 input>hidden which are dropped on another div.

At drop event i want to fetch values of both input>hidden in a variable.

Below is my draggable structure.

```
<div class="srcfield" title="Drag and map Last Name!">
<span><img src="images/cursor1.png" height="14" width="14" border="0"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;First Name</span>
<input type="hidden" name="FieldName" value="FirstName"/>
<input type="hidden" name="SourceType" value="B"/>
```

When i do:

```
ui.draggable.children("input").attr("name")
```

it gives me first hidden field only.

How can i get second hidden field

thanks
WK

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your HTML isn't correct.

Secondly `ui.draggable.children("input")` is not a single element and `.attr("name")` is not the value. If you want to fetch the values, you have to iterate the `ui.draggable.children("input").attr("name")` and use `.val()`

For instance:

```
ui.draggable.children("input").each(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

If you want to get only a specific value, consider adding classes to the inputs and addressing them by that class. For more info about used functions, check the [jQuery's docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)